# How to change the a axis to a time series in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, stacked-area-chart

I'm trying to replicate the graph provided at https://www.chicagofed.org/research/data/cfnai/current-data since I will be needing graphs for data sets soon that look like this. I'm almost there, I can't seem to figure out how to change the x axis to the dates when using ggplot2. Specifically, I would like to change it to the dates in the Date column. I tried about a dozen ways and nothing is working. The data for this graph is under indexes on the website. Here's my code and the graph where dataSet is the data from the website:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(reshape2) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(lubridate) 
df = data.frame(time = index(dataSet), melt(as.data.frame(dataSet)))
df
str(df)
df$data1.Date = as.Date(as.character(df$data1.Date))
str(df)
replicaPlot1 = ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) + 
  geom_area(aes(colour = variable, fill = variable)) +
  stat_summary(fun = sum, geom = "line", size = 0.4) +
  labs(title = "Chicago Fed National Activity Index (CFNAI) Current Data")
replicaPlot1 + scale_x_continuous(name = "time", breaks = waiver(), labels = waiver(), limits = 
df$data1.Date)
replicaPlot1
```

Any sort of help on this would be very much appreciated!

[G:\BOS\Common\R-Projects\Graphs\Replica of Chicago Fed National Acitivty index (PCA)\dataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFfJM.jpg)

Comment: Is your variable `time` numeric? And `limits = df$data1.Date` sets axis limits, not axis labels. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your intention with `data.frame(time = index(dataSet), melt(as.data.frame(dataSet)))`. When I download the data and read via `readxl::read_excel` I got a nice tibble with a date(time) column which after reshaping via `tidyr::pivot_longer` could easily be plotted and by making use of `scale_x_datetime` has a nicely formatted date axis:

Using just the first 20 rows of data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)

df <- pivot_longer(df, -Date, names_to = "variable")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = value)) +
  geom_area(aes(colour = variable, fill = variable)) +
  stat_summary(fun = sum, geom = "line", size = 0.4) +
  labs(title = "Chicago Fed National Activity Index (CFNAI) Current Data") +
  scale_x_datetime(name = "time")
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**DATA**

```
# Data downloaded from https://www.chicagofed.org/~/media/publications/cfnai/cfnai-data-series-xlsx.xlsx?la=en

# df <- readxl::read_excel("cfnai-data-series-xlsx.xlsx")

# dput(head(df, 20))
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(
  -87004800, -84412800, -81734400,
  -79142400, -76464000, -73785600, -71193600, -68515200, -65923200,
  -63244800, -60566400, -58060800, -55382400, -52790400, -50112000,
  -47520000, -44841600, -42163200, -39571200, -36892800
), tzone = "UTC", class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
)), P_I = c(
  -0.26, 0.16, -0.43, -0.09, -0.19, 0.58, -0.05,
  0.21, 0.51, 0.33, -0.1, 0.12, 0.07, 0.04, 0.35, 0.04, -0.1, 0.14,
  0.05, 0.11
), EU_H = c(
  -0.06, -0.09, 0.01, 0.04, 0.1, 0.22, -0.04,
  0, 0.32, 0.16, -0.2, 0.34, 0.06, 0.17, 0.17, 0.07, 0.12, 0.12,
  0.15, 0.18
), C_H = c(
  -0.01, 0.01, -0.05, 0.08, -0.07, -0.01,
  0.12, -0.11, 0.1, 0.15, -0.04, 0.04, 0.17, -0.03, 0.05, 0.08,
  0.09, 0.05, -0.06, 0.09
), SO_I = c(
  -0.01, -0.07, -0.08, 0.02,
  -0.16, 0.22, -0.08, -0.07, 0.38, 0.34, -0.13, -0.1, 0.08, -0.07,
  0.06, 0.07, 0.12, -0.3, 0.35, 0.14
), CFNAI = c(
  -0.34, 0.02, -0.55,
  0.04, -0.32, 1, -0.05, 0.03, 1.32, 0.97, -0.46, 0.39, 0.38, 0.11,
  0.63, 0.25, 0.22, 0.01, 0.49, 0.52
), CFNAI_MA3 = c(
  NA, NA, -0.29,
  -0.17, -0.28, 0.24, 0.21, 0.33, 0.43, 0.77, 0.61, 0.3, 0.1, 0.29,
  0.37, 0.33, 0.37, 0.16, 0.24, 0.34
), DIFFUSION = c(
  NA, NA, -0.17,
  -0.14, -0.21, 0.16, 0.11, 0.17, 0.2, 0.5, 0.41, 0.28, 0.2, 0.32,
  0.36, 0.32, 0.33, 0.25, 0.31, 0.47
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you very very much for your help! I was stuck on this and now everything works perfectly. I hope you have a great rest of your day :)